# Dynamic adding new models into viewer

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, autodesk-viewer, blazor-webassembly

I want to create a web page where in the left side, the model thumbnail will be displayed and in the right side, I need to show said model. I found the solution to initially load multiple models, as seen below:

```
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () =>
        loadModels([
            { urn: "urn1", xform: { x: -60, y: 0, z: 0 } },
            { urn: "urn2", xform: { x: 60, y: 0, z: 0 } },
            { urn: "urn3", xform: { x: 50, y: 0, z: 50 } },
        ])
    );
```

and using the following function

```
       Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(viewerOptions, () => {

            const div = document.getElementById('forgeViewer');
            viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D(div, { extensions: ["DragControlExtension"] });
            viewer.start();
            urns.map((m) => {
                Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(`urn:${m.urn}`, (doc) => {
                    var viewables = doc.getRoot().getDefaultGeometry();
                    viewer.loadDocumentNode(doc, viewables, {
                        placementTransform: (new THREE.Matrix4()).setPosition(m.xform),
                        keepCurrentModels: true,
                        globalOffset: { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 }
                    })
                        .then(onLoadFinished);
                });

            })
        });
```

Now, my question is: 'Can I drag a new model at runtime'. Also, is it possible to move the existing model by dragging.

After `Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer`, is there any event or method which may help? (Some reference will also help.)

Answer (score 1):

Once you loaded the model you can move it around by modifying its **placementTransform** - e.g. if **secondModel** is the one you just added and are trying to move around with e.g. keys on the keyboard, you could do this:

```
document.onkeydown = event => {
  if (!event.shiftKey)
    return;

  if (event.code === "ArrowRight") {
    let tr = secondModel.getPlacementTransform();
    // move along X axis
    tr.elements[12] += 1;
    secondModel.setPlacementTransform(tr);
  }

  if (event.code === "ArrowLeft") {
    let tr = secondModel.getPlacementTransform();
    // move along X axis
    tr.elements[12] -= 1;
    secondModel.setPlacementTransform(tr);
  }
};
```

You can find more details about it here: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/dynamic-model-placement

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have two more queries will it be possible to add new model in existing viewer with model and Can I select a model and move that model around?

Comment: 1) Yes you can keep adding models to the Viewer
2) Yes you can move any of the models the same way as done in the article. How you select the model you want to move is up to you. Based on their name, based on their index (1st loaded vs 3rd loaded), letting a user select an object from it

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you provide me some link like above to add model in viewer where model is already there in the viewer? Also is there any document in depth about the method with explanation?

Comment: You can just keep calling viewer.loadDocumentNode() with the same arguments to keep adding the same model again and again