# How can I add objects by drag and drop on autodesk forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, forge, autodesk-model-derivative

how can I add the objects we have produced on the viewer by drag and drop. Like adding a window to the wall of the house? Is there an example or application made for this? or a resource you can recommend?

Comment: Does the answer here help?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66149698/dynamic-adding-new-models-into-viewer/66217724

Comment: @AdamNagy similar to this, but the difference is being able to drag and drop models from outside. And move the model we left behind again

Comment: You mean this? https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/drag-and-drop-models-viewer

Comment: You are wonderful @AdamNagy. I am currently working for movement via input. I will look at the first opportunity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown in https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/dynamic-model-placement you can load and move models around using their placementTransform: model.**getPlacementTransform**() / model.**setPlacementTransform**()

You can also combine this with the drag and drop functionality of the browser. Once the user reached the Viewer while dragging, we can start loading the given model. Once the model is loaded, as the user keeps dragging around we can modify the placement of the dragged model.
See https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/drag-and-drop-models-viewer

Comment: thank you Adam. i tried it now and it works. but when I upload an external model, the extensions I installed earlier do not work on that model. And I guess the extensions work based on models. For example the transform extension works on the first model, but it doesn't work when I load the new model.  I think it originates from here https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-extensions/blob/master/public/extensions/TransformationExtension/contents/main.js#L144

Comment: Right. Many sample codes (like the one you pointed out) are not written for a multi-model environment. You would need to modify them for that.
This might be useful for that: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/multi-model-refresher

Comment: thank you Adam.I edited the tool now I provide movement in multiple models. Now I will calculate the coordinates and add them to the same place with the mouse while the model is being drag-dropped.